# How can I add a string or function that adds +1 to the date? Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, function, powerpoint

I am attempting to grab images w/ a future date from a website. My current function is below. How do I make it so that my

```
" & Format$(Date, "YYYYMMDD00") & "
```

contains a +1 DD variable so the function knows to pull today's date +1. I.e, today is 02/08/22, I'm looking for something that will modify the DD so it grab's 02/09/22's images.

Hope this makes sense; any advice is greatly appreciated

So I tried

```
Dim d As DateTime
d = Now()

d = d + 1 ''# => tomorrow
```

and what comes up is a box saying "Automation type not supported in visual basic"

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Change `Date` to `Date + 1`?

Comment: exactly what u suggested